# How can I use an at command in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, at-job

I am trying to use the Unix `at` command (for setting a job to run at a certain time) in a shell script. The time will be specified by user input using getopts and optarg which seem to be working fine, the problem is `at`. How do I write the `at` command into the script to run at a certain time based on input from the user?

Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd say

```
at now +10 minutes <<< "rm -rf /tmp/tobedeleted"
```

For multiline, consider a "HERE-doc"

```
at now +10 minutes <<ENDMARKER
rm -rf /tmp/tobedeleted
echo all done | mail -s 'completion notification' sysadmin@example.com
ENDMARKER
```

Comment: Thank you so much sehe. Super fast and helpful answer! it was the <<< and <<ENDMARKER that I had no idea how to do.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.